# Set Width of <div> tag

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

i have a `test.aspx` page where there is a `<div class="outerdiv1">` and there is a `<asp:Repeater/>` inside this `Div` which will generate some more `Divs` in `outerDiv1`.

```
<div class="outerDiv1">
   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <div class='<%# (Eval("Walkable").ToString() == "1") ? "isWalkable" : "isWall" %>' runat="server" id="Wall">
       </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Following is the `css` for `outerDiv1`.

```
.outerDiv1
{
   max-width:0px;
   overflow:auto;
   overflow: auto;           
}
```

by default the `max-width` is `0px`.
i have width of the `outerdiv1` stored in Database.
how can i set `max-width` in css of `outerDiv1` with value i already have in Database?is it possible with jquery?
the backend code is in c#.

Comment: Sounds like the job for some inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get this value from database, and put it in `style` attribute of `outerDiv1`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, you can use inline styles.

Set the 'outerdiv1' div to runat=server and use style attribute.

Something like below.

```
<div class="outerdiv1" runat="server" style="max-width: <%=Value%>;"/>
```

where Value could be a public property that holds the max-width data from your DB.

Comment: i tried it but not working     `<div class="outerDiv1" runat="server" style="max-width:<%=floorWidth%>">` and  `int floorWidth=floor.width;`

Comment: what does the rendered css look like in F12 tools?